# Pandas - only keep first instance of a column value (replace rest with empty string)

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas df, composed like:

```
X = pandas.DataFrame(
   [
      [1, "abc"], 
      [2, "abc"], 
      [3, "def"],
      [4, "def"],
      [5, "def"],
      [6, "def"],
      [7, "ghi"], 
      [8, "jkl"],
      [9, "jkl"]
   ]
)
X.columns = ["id", "value"]
```

I want it to be a bit more memory friendly, in such a way that all the unique `value` items should just have their first instance present in the df, and rest of their consecutive instances be filled with an empty string.

Essentially, I would like to convert the above `df` into something like:

```
[
   [1, "abc"],
   [2, ""],
   [3, ""],
   [4, ""],
   [5, ""],
   [6, ""],
   [7, "ghi"],
   [8, "jkl"],
   [9, ""]
]
```

My question is: Is there a panda-ized or some sort of dataframe-ish way of achieving this? I can totally convert it into the desired form by iterating over the dataframe, which I think (and actually is) a very slow process if your dataframe is actually large.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `X.loc[X['value'].duplicated(),'value']=''` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do :

```py
X['value'] = X.value.where(X.value != X.value.shift(), '')
```

Comment: This gets rid of every value in the column except the first, and my column contains three different strings, each repeated numerous times. Based on the question, if this is the answer, then I would expect that this code would leave just the first occurrence of each of these strings in my column...not just the first value in the column.